# set selected radio button asp.net MVC 4 Razer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, radio-button, selecteditem

I know you can set the selected value of a dropdownlist in asp.net mvc 4 razor via

```
ViewData["answeredAnswer"] = answeredId;
```

but isn't there something similar to set the selected value of a set of radiobuttons?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have 3 radio buttons with 1, 2, 3 values.

```
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="r2" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="r3" value="3" />
```

Firstly, you take value from `ViewData` (or ViewBag, Tempdata), then make checked one of them.

```
@{
    int id = 0;
    if(ViewData["answeredAnswer"] != null) { id = (int)ViewData["answeredAnswer"]; }   
}

<input type="radio" name="r1" value="1" @if(id == 1){<text>checked="checked"</text>} />
<input type="radio" name="r2" value="2" @if(id == 2){<text>checked="checked"</text>} />
<input type="radio" name="r3" value="3" @if(id == 3){<text>checked="checked"</text>} />
```

Comment: Good. Nice Solution.

Comment: @Jhoonbey thank you for your great Solution,but what is purpose of <text> tag?? why not just use @if(id == 1){checked="checked"} ???

Comment: If I am not wrong I had tested it in MVC 3 and without any HTML tag, it was not working, it was recognizing "checked" as C# code, not HTML code, that is why I covered it with a simple HTML tag.